# C DLL function got char* parameter and I want to import in C# project

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a DLL wrote in C and I want to export the function :

`__declspec( dllexport ) int GetDllVersion(char *Version);`

and I have

```
class DllSolderMask
{
     [DllImport("Dll.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
     public static extern int GetDllVersion(ref string version);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string strVersion;

        DllSolderMask.AltixDllVersion(ref strVersion);

        Console.WriteLine(strVersion.ToString());
}
```

The **char *Version** is obviously a character's array and so **ref string strVersion** could do the job but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string version` instead of `ref string version`.

Comment: I don't think `ref` is necessary

Comment: yeah I already tried [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] it doesn't match to :/

Comment: The name seems to imply it's going to fill the `version`, but then the API is a disaster waiting to happen, since there's no parameter for passing the length of the output buffer. If it does do that, then pass a `StringBuilder` that you've initialized to the desired capacity. (And mark the parameter as `[Out]`.)

Comment: Yes, the `StringBuilder` will definitely work.

Comment: You cannot use string since this function scribbles into the string buffer.  StringBuilder required.  Do note that it is a very dangerous function because you cannot tell it how much Capacity you gave the builder.  Aim high, 666 is recommended.

Comment: I Tried 
`public static extern int DllVersion(StringBuilder version);`
with 
`StringBuilder strVersion = new StringBuilder(150);`
still the same with attribute [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] on _version_
both don't work

Comment: Why are you struggling here, guessing wildly? There are countless examples online showing how to do this? Please make some effort to learn rather than bothering his site with your guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how to properly use StringBuilder :

```
[DllImport("AltixDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static int AltixDllVersion([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder DllVersion);

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
DllSolderMask.AltixDllVersion(str);
lblDll.Text = str.ToString();
```

the byte array way is not dynamic and it requires me to know the space I need in my array declaration, and it's not accurate.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to pass a byte[] like this :

```
    byte[] strVersion = new byte[256];

    DllSolderMask.AltixDllVersion(strVersion);

    string myString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(strVersion);
    Console.WriteLine(myString);
```

I think that from C++ point of view, char* is just a pointer to an array of 8-bit entries.

Comment: ok strange that works but I did tried to do this earlier maybe didn't put enough size in the byte array thanks anyway